# I want to loop inside the JSON object , when elements to the objects are added dynamically |AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I want to show the whole JSON in tabular format and as I am adding more and more values in the JSON like a product3 array in the JSON below  may get added dynamically I want my code to read it and loop through it as well dynamically

I have my JSON as:

```
    $scope.tableContent = [
        {
            id: 1,
            sks: 'sk1',
            product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2', 'micro m4'],
            product2: ['prod2']
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            sks: 'sk2',
            product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2'],
            product2: ['prod4']
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            sks: 'sk3',
            product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2'],
            product2: ['prod6']
        }];
```

and i have my code in HTML as

```
<div class="row" id="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat="x in tableContent">
    <div class="cell"> {{x.sks}} </div>
       <div class="cell" > {{x.product1}} </div>
          <div class="cell" > {{x.product2}} </div>
              <div class="cellD">
```

Although I want to do something like this to make it work.

```
<div class="row" id="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat="x in tableContent" ng-repeat="y in x">
<div class="cell" > {{x.y}} </div>
<div class="cellD">
```

However the above code isn't working the way I desired and I have to mention all the elements of the JSON object separately.

Comment: You have to include an angular controller for this to work

Comment: I am very new to angular I cant think of how to do this @margarita

Comment: I think you should read angular docs first, this question presumes you have rad at least a bit by yourself.

Comment: Try this one: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: `<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>` Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-repeat. You can add more data dynamically and use ng-repeat as per your scenario.

```js
angular.module("exApp", [])
  .controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.tableContent = [{
        id: 1,
        sks: 'sk1',
        product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2', 'micro m4'],
        product2: ['prod2'],
        product3:['prod3']
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        sks: 'sk2',
        product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2'],
        product2: ['prod4']
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        sks: 'sk3',
        product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2'],
        product2: ['prod6']
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="row" id="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat="x in tableContent">
    <div class="cell" ng-repeat="(key, value) in x" ng-if="key !== 'id'"> {{value}} 
    <p ng-repeat="val in x.product1">{{val}}</p>
    <p ng-repeat="val in x.product2">{{val}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cellD"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The value in sks is coming in the end of the table for some reasons

Comment: I want the data to be shown in the same order as they are in the JSON but the sks are shown in the end of the table ,below the product values , which is not desired

Comment: After ng-repeat="(key, value) in x" give  x.sks as a first tag. Why you weird.?

Comment: I dont want to give tags , otherwise it will not work as desired ,as infinite number of data can be pushed dynamically in the JSON , i cant give tags to all , all the time

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209740/angularjs-update-scope-in-ng-include-and-ng-repeat/43210382#43210382

Answer (score 1):

you can use nested `ng-repeat` to achieve this.

refer below code snippet.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.tableContent = [{
        id: 1,
        sks: 'sk1',
        product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2', 'micro m4'],
        product2: ['prod2']
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        sks: 'sk2',
        product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2'],
        product2: ['prod4']
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        sks: 'sk3',
        product1: ['micro m1', 'micro m2'],
        product2: ['prod6']
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row" id="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat="x in tableContent">
    <div class="cell" ng-repeat="(key, value) in x" ng-if="key !== 'id'"> {{value}} </div>
    <div class="cellD"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked but the field SK1 and Sk2 is shown in the end of the table, I do not want that to happen